# Renaming and Moving Files on a Mapped Network Drive using PHP

Tags: php, windows, networking, nas

I am generating a small script that **manipulates** a file name, **renames** the file, and **moves** it to a directory within it's current directory.

The problem (*I think*) is that I am running a local **PHP Script** from my computer and trying to have it do the manipulation on a **network drive** (R:\ in this case)

I decided, since I'm using Windows 7, that I'll be using the **rename()** function.  Here is the snippet of code..

```
if (!empty($_REQUEST['uploaded_file']))
    rename("R:\\".$fileName, "R:\\Movies\\".$newFileName);
```

*Note: **$filename** and **$newFileName** are pulled earlier in the script*

The resulting error is:

```
Warning: rename(R:\movie.title.2011.avi,R:\Movies\Movie Title [2011].avi):
                      The system cannot find the path specified. (code: 3)
```

The code use to work for a while, but for whatever reason, all of the sudden, it doesn't want to work anymore.

I'm not sure if using the rename scheme is the best approach for getting this done..  My Synology DS1010+ didn't like me using SFTP to connect and rename too many times.. It eventually started to refuse connections, so I needed to do this differently..

**Environment Information:**

Operating System:

- Windows 7 Ultimate x64
- PHP Version: 5.4.4

**FileZilla Connection Attempt:**

```
Status: Connecting to 192.168.5.25:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220 Diniz-Stora FTP server ready.
Command:    USER admin
Response:   331 Password required for admin.
Command:    PASS **********
Response:   230 User admin logged in.
Status: Connected
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is current directory.
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Type set to I.
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (24,63,165,211,217,0)
Command:    LIST
```

Comment: What version of PHP are you running?

Comment: I would suggest to find the reason why sftp is not usable any more. IT is not humanistic psychology with servers getting annoyed. Fix the problem and use sftp which certainly is better and more reliable than any self written attempt for a simple rename.

Comment: @afuzzyllama I am running PHP 5.4.4.. Sorry for not stating that, I'll update the OP

Comment: Does your server have permission to write to the NAS?  Also, have you tried other things like [copy()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) to see if that works?

Comment: @arkascha I tried to ask the company back in July, however, after 141 views, no one came through with even an attempt of a solution: http://forum.synology.com/enu/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=54284

Comment: @afuzzyllama From my Windows 7 PC (Where the script is running), I am able to read/write.  It's mapped to Drive Letter R:\

I am going to attempt to perform a static copy() to see if that fails too.

Comment: Even after "141 views": IT is not magic. Find the problem. There is one. A good start usually is reading the error message.

Comment: @arkascha I logged into my Synology DS1010+..  I don't have any logs, the last time I tried doing the SFTP method was back in July..  I'm not 100% which sftp function I want to attempt to use either..

Comment: ?? well just use a sftp client your system has installed and see what happens. Where is the problem? Ah, sorry, I just see you are still using MS-Windows. Then obviously there is no sftp client installed. There are good free implementations available though. Try google.

Comment: Using FileZilla I attempted to connect and it hangs at the List Command (Appended to OP)

Comment: very nice... allow a user to rename any file on the drive and move it whever they want under any name on that same drive...ouch

Comment: The 'hang' on a list file is a typical sign of a network problem. And that absolutely clearly shows you are not using sftp, but plain ftp or maybe ftps. Read about the networking problems envolved with plain ftp. A very interesting lecture.

Comment: I'm going to point out the obvious here, but maybe firewall/antivirus can cause issues...

Comment: I updated my Synology DSM to Version 4.1 (Latest for my device).. SFTP is now implemented and works :)..